# AsyncTask in the ThreadPool

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpool

How could I run the AsyncTask in the thread pool? method `executeOnExecutor(exec, params)` I cannot use, because it requires API level 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not run an AsyncTask in a custom thread pool. AsyncTasks are already managed by a thread pool through Android. You can see this by debugging your application and watch the thread pool grow as you create AsyncTasks.